# Yarn Socket connection timeout

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

When I try to install a package using Yarn I get following error:

```
yarn add @mantine/prism    
yarn add v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@mantine%2fprism: Socket connection timeout".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/rayorole/code/etherspay/etherspay-coming-soon/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

I also tried using NPM, but this loads indefinetly with no error at all. I assume its the same error with NPM

I tried rebooting my system, updating using apt-get update, changing networks, ... nothing works the error persists. I have a stable internet connection

I did get following warning trying to update my system:

```
W: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have found a solution.
I added following lines to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

After that, I applied the changes using

```
sudo sysctl -p
```